# Multiple filters with Jquery

Tags: jquery, filtering

I have some div´s in my page (build with php+jquery) and I want to filter them according to their attributes (if there´s more than 1 attribute filtering, than it will narrow down the search).
The div´s look like this:

```
<div id="solicitacoes">
    <div id='1' title='Mike' status='18' analista='23'>Whatever content 1</div>
    <div id='2' title='John' status='16' analista='46'>Whatever content 2</div>
    <div id='3' title='Tom' status='2' analista='49'>Whatever content 3</div>
    <div id='4' title='Mike' status='4' analista='23'>Whatever content 4</div>
    <div id='5' title='Kate' status='3' analista='32'>Whatever content 5</div>
    <div id='6' title='Steve' status='1' analista='14'>Whatever content 6</div>
</div>
```

Then, I have a form to filter the div´s attributes:

```
<div id="filtros">
<form id="filtroSolicitacoes" type="post" name="filtroSolicitacoes">
Protocolo: <input type="text" name="filtroProtocolo" id="filtroProtocolo" size="5"/>
Solicitante: <input type="text" name="filtroSolicitante" id="filtroSolicitante" size="10"/>
Status: 
<select name="filtroStatus" id="filtroStatus">
<option value="0">-- Selecione Status--</option>
<option value="3">Aguardando Aprova&ccedil;&atilde;o</option>
<option value="18">Encaminhado</option>
<option value="2">Iniciado</option>
<option value="1">N&atilde;o Iniciado</option>
<option value="4">Pendente de Esclarecimento</option>
<option value="16">Reiniciado</option>
<option value="6">Reprovado</option>
</select>
Analista: 
<select name="filtroAnalista" id="filtroAnalista">
    <option value="23">Robert</option>
    <option value="46">Allan</option>
    <option value="49">Edward</option>
    <option value="32">Jake</option>
    <option value="14">Stella</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" id="filtrar" style="float:right; margin-right:10px">:: Filtrar ::</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Now, I´ve alredy done most of the Jquery part and the filter is working ---> But **I want to NARROW DOWN the search if there´s more than 1 filtering attribute, NOT to concatenate it**, and that´s what´s happening with my code
 bellow:

```
$("#filtroSolicitacoes").submit(function() {
    $("#solicitacoes > div").show();
    var filtroProtocolo = $("#filtroProtocolo").val();
    var filtroSolicitante = $("#filtroSolicitante").val().toUpperCase();
    var filtroStatus = $("#filtroStatus").val();
    var filtroAnalista = $("#filtroAnalista").val();
    var filtroResultado = $("#filtroResultado:checked").length;

    var filtros = "[id=filtros]";

    if(filtroStatus !== "0"){
        filtros +=",[status='"+filtroStatus+"']";
    }
    if(filtroProtocolo !== ""){
        filtros +=",[id='"+filtroProtocolo+"']";
    }
    if(filtroSolicitante !== ""){
        filtros +=",[title*='"+filtroSolicitante+"']";
    }
    if(filtroAnalista !== "0"){
        filtros +=",[analista='"+filtroAnalista+"']";
    }

    if(filtros !== "[id=filtros]"){
        $("#solicitacoes > div:not("+filtros+")").hide();
    }
    return false;
});
```

I´ve tried to use "&&" instead of "," in

```
filtros +=",[analista='"+filtroAnalista+"']";
```

But it didn´t work.

any ideas?

PS: Sorry for my poor English, I´m brazilian :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the filter() function:

```
var filteredList = elements
                      .filter("[status=status1]")
                      .filter("[title*=something]");
// and so on
```

In your example:

```
$("#filtroSolicitacoes").submit(function() {
    $("#solicitacoes > div").show();
    var filtroProtocolo = $("#filtroProtocolo").val();
    var filtroSolicitante = $("#filtroSolicitante").val().toUpperCase();
    var filtroStatus = $("#filtroStatus").val();
    var filtroAnalista = $("#filtroAnalista").val();
    var filtroResultado = $("#filtroResultado:checked").length;

    var elements = $("[id=filtros]");

    if(filtroStatus !== "0"){
        elements = elements.filter("[status='"+filtroStatus+"']");
    }
    if(filtroProtocolo !== ""){
        elements = elements.filter("[id='"+filtroProtocolo+"']");
    }

    // and so on

    $("#solicitatcoes > div").not(elements).hide();

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Idiotic question (I know, so forgive me in advance):
The filter function works the other way around, so the var filteredList would be the div´s that I want to show, right? So I would just replace it here?  
$("#solicitacoes > div:not("+filtros+")").hide();
>> $("#solicitacoes > div:not("+filteredList +")").hide();

Comment: @Philippe--I gave you a point for your answer because I've been looking for a solution to this same problem for months! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Just remove the commas.

So instead of:

```
filtros +=",[status='"+filtroStatus+"']";
```

Use

```
filtros +="[status='"+filtroStatus+"']";
```

You want your resulting query to look like this:

```
"[status=status][title*='whatever']"
```

Also, the way you are calling it isn't filtering it correctly. This is how I would change your function to make it work (You can view a [working demo](http://jsbin.com/urume) of your code, and [play with it.](http://jsbin.com/urume/edit)):

```
$("#filtroSolicitacoes").submit(function() {
    var filtroProtocolo = $("#filtroProtocolo").val();
    var filtroSolicitante = $("#filtroSolicitante").val().toUpperCase();
    var filtroStatus = $("#filtroStatus").val();
    var filtroAnalista = $("#filtroAnalista").val();
    var filtroResultado = $("#filtroResultado:checked").length;

    var filtros = "";

    if(filtroStatus !== "0"){
        filtros +="[status='"+filtroStatus+"']";
    }
    if(filtroProtocolo !== ""){
        filtros +="[id='"+filtroProtocolo+"']";
    }
    if(filtroSolicitante !== ""){
        filtros +="[title*='"+filtroSolicitante+"']";
    }
    if(filtroAnalista !== "0"){
        filtros +="[analista='"+filtroAnalista+"']";
    }

    if(filtros !== ""){
        $("#solicitacoes > div").hide().filter(filtros).show();
    } else {
        $("#solicitacoes > div").show();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @Let I updated my answer... sorry didn't notice the use of `not` the first time through. I also added a working demo of the finished code using JSBin.

Answer (score 1):

Put the name of the attribute on each element and the solution will be more dynamic, it only needs the "data-form" attribute to select the correct elements:

```
$("#filtroSolicitacoes").on("submit", function(){

    $("#solicitacoes div").show();

    var filter = "";

    $(this).find("[data-form]").each(function(){

        if( $(this).val() != "" ) filter += ("[" + $(this).attr("data-form") + "='" + $(this).val() + "']");

    });

    if(filter.length > 0) $("#solicitacoes div").not(filter).hide();

    return false;

});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/e4otmc37/)