# JQuery filter for anchor text OR title attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to filter on title OR anchor text so that eg "lala2" OR "text2" OR "2" would toggle the others away (1 in this case)...I want the Anchors which don't contain that string to disappear.

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">

<div id="myList">
  <a class="someclass" title="title text lalalala1" href="blah.com">some anchor text1</a>
  <a class="someclass" title="title text lalalala2" href="blah2.com">some anchor text2</a>
  etc       
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myList a").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

Tried:
Filtering on this.title

```
$("#myList a, #myList a[title]").filter(function()
```

and with and without  $(this).toggle.parent()
And a few other things. 
it works for text within the anchor, ie toggles away anchors NOT containing 'value', but can't get it to do it for BOTH Anchor title attribute and straight anchor text.

Comment: Maybe try it this way instead? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2029873/11700321

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes:

• `keyup → input`, which works more predictable - even if you press multiple keys at once, also works on copy-paste.

• `filter → each` — just required any loop, but not filtered element list.

• `$(this).text().toLowerCase()` — added parentheses to text() — it's a jQuery function.

• `includes()` — native JavaScript string method. Checks, if one string includes another string. It's preferred to use, if you want just to check, but not get it's index. Returns `true` or `false`

• `||` — means "OR" in boolean expressions (By the way `&&` — "AND" )

```js
$("#myInput").on("input", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

  $("#myList a").each(function() {
    $(this).toggle(
      $(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(value) ||
      $(this).attr('title').toLowerCase().includes(value)
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="type 'lala2'...">

<div id="myList">
  <a class="someclass" title="title text lalalala1" href="blah.com">some anchor text1</a>
  <a class="someclass" title="title text lalalala2" href="blah2.com">some anchor text2</a> etc
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what was needed and great explanation. Thank you.